# Permission is denied when moving file from repository to another

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop

Assume that I want to move a csv file from `/home/user` to `/hdfs/data/adhoc/PR/02/RDO0/OUTPUT/`

So :

```
hadoop fs mkdir -m 777 /hdfs/data/adhoc/PR/02/RDO0/OUTPUT/

hadoop fs -moveFromLocal RDO07J420.csv $OUTPUT_FILE_OCRE/MGM7J420-${OPC_DISO8601}.csv
```

But, I get this problem :

> moveFromLocal: Permission denied: user=fs191, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/hdfs/data/adhoc/PR/02/RDO0/OUTPUT/MGM7J420-.csv.*COPYING*":RDO0-mdoPR:bfRDO0:drwxr-x---

Comment: Do you have permission to remove the file RDO07J420  from the local folder ? permission to remove the source files is needed for 'moveFromLocal'

Answer (score 0):

You local user does not have write rights in hdfs. 
Try

```
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -moveFromLocal RDO07J420.csv $OUTPUT_FILE_OCRE/MGM7J420-${OPC_DISO8601}.csv
```

hdfs is the root user and has write rights, but I suggest managing users and permissions better

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2755708&seqNum=3